# onsen navigator postpush event listeners in multiple angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Suppose I've 3 controllers, each associated with different `<ons-page>`:

- `C1 (v1.html)`, `C2 (v2.html)`, `C3 (v3.html)`

I fire a `nav.pushPage()` from `v1.html` to `v2.html`, and then from there to `v3.html`. I'm trying to initialize scope variables for `C2` and `C3`, using `postpush` event listener.

Now, what I'm confused about is the placement of `nav.on('postpush')` event listeners. If I put it in both `C2` and `C3`, then while moving to `v3.html`, both `C2` and `C3` event listeners are fired. After going through some docs, and issues, it seems like expected behaviour. But should I be worried about that?

I tried disabling the events using `nav.off('postpush')` method, on `$scope.$on('$destroy')` in all the controllers, but it doesn't seem to work, as `pushPage()` on `v1.html` will not destroy the `C1's` scope. What's the work-around for that? Where should I disable the listener?

Let me know if code snippet is required for this, as all the above thing are related to onsen API, which should be quite understandable.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the problem is that you cannot distinguish in C2 between a `postpush` C1->C2 and C2->C3? In that case, the `postpush` event has "enterPage" and "leavePage" properties that can be useful.

Comment: @FranDios Yeah I'm using those 2 properties right now. But suppose I've binded controllers `C2` in 2 views. So, that controller will be created twice, thus registering the `postpush` listeners twice. So, when I push from `v2` to `v3`, `C2` scope is not destroyed. And then pushing from `v3` to `v4 (C2)` again registers `C2` scope. We've duplicate listeners registered now. How to get the previous one off?

Comment: @FranDios I can't do it on scope destroyed, as `v2` page scope is still active.

Comment: the `postpush` should be set in navigator's scope with `ons-postpush` attribute. In that case, even if you change pages inside navigator, the listener will be registered only once. If you want to initialise stuff when the animation is finished, you can set a boolean in the navigator's controller on `postpush` and then initialise values on pages controllers depending on that boolean (i.e. `ng-if="$parent.isAnimationFinished"`) or something similar.

Comment: @FranDios Ok. Will look into `ons-postpush` attribute. Didn't know about that.. BTW, can you please write an answer to the question?

Comment: Yes, I didn't write it before because I was not sure if I understood the problem.

Comment: @FranDios Ok, so `ons-postpush` seems like a good way here. It works. So, should I combine all the postpush event listeners in a single method in root controller, and call that in `ons-postpush`? And share the variables using Angular services? And when will the listeners be registered? Will that be the first thing to trigger controller initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postpush` event listener in AngularJS should be set with the `ons-postpush` attribute that navigator and other components have: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#attributes

It takes a function in the scope of the navigator and use it as a listener. Like this, it will be set only once so there is no need to worry about many listeners being fired at the same time.

In that listener you can set up variables when the animation ends or anything you need, and then access them from the `ons-page` controllers. It's very likely your `ons-page` controllers will be children of navigator's controller, so perhaps you can use `$parent` from them. Also you could fire sub-events and catch them from the page controllers or simply use services to share anything you need.

The event is fired after the page element is linked, so I believe the controller will be initialised before the event is fired. You can use the methods mentioned before to "trigger" your initialisation when you want (services, parent controller or sub-events).

Perhaps `onTransitionEnd` callback could also be useful for you: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#method-pushPage

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is the difference in using `onTransitionEnd` and `postpush` listener? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: I'm using `onTransitionEnd` method now, to set some values in services for the next page to be used. But as you said, the next controller is initialized before the `onTransitionEnd` method is executed, and thus it doesn't see the changes that will be done `onTransitionEnd`. I can do that thing with `prepush` event listener. But that will make me write all codes in the single controller associated with my `navigator`. Is there any other way here, to call method of current controller, before moving to another controller?

Comment: Thank you so much @FranDios for your answer. It has helped me lot. My application now looks much cleaner after I refactored it, following your suggestions. Getting closer to onsen now :)